# Install plyvel with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, leveldb

I'm trying to install plyvel with pip on Ubuntu but I keep getting an error message "Failed building wheel for plyvel". The installation terminates with the following message

```
"plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h""
```

I've seen an older post saying to install

```
libleveldb-dev
libleveldb1v5
```

And I have both installed but still cannot install plyvel. Is there anything else I can try? And are there any other leveldb packages for python?

Comment: have you tried this `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: @TamilSelvan I already have that installed

Comment: Same issue. Still occurring

Answer (score 3):

By default pip tries to install version plyvel-1.3.0. So I tried choosing version 1.2.0 and the installation worked. Anyone having this problem try this:

```
pip install plyvel==1.2.0
```